# Show that $n!e^n/n^{n+1/2} \leq e^{1/(4n)}C$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, approximation

Consider the sequence $r_n = n!e^n/n^{n+1/2}$ for positive integers $n$. It's straightforward to show that $r_n$ converges to some finite limit (applying the monotone convergence theorem to this decreasing sequence). Call the limit value $C$ and show that for all $n$:

$$r_n \leq e^{1/(4n)}C$$

I'm working on a proof by induction, but I'm having trouble with the induction step.

Note, this is used in a proof of Stirling's approximation.

Comment: By Stirling's formula $C=\sqrt{2\pi}$.If you look at the proof of that formula, you will prove what you need.

Comment: Maybe I added the comment too late :)

Comment: @user158834 OP is trying to verify a step of Stirling's formula.

Comment: @UmbertoP.: I am not sure the OP knows Stirling's formula. Otherwise (s)he would not denote $\sqrt{2\pi}$ by $C$. But, yes, his inequality follows from the standard proof of that formula.

Comment: @user158834 the last line of OP is "Note, this is used in a proof of Stirling's approximation"

Comment: @UmbertoP.: Indeed. There is a nice survey of the proof by K. Conrad: https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/analysis/stirling.pdf .

Comment: Have you tried taking the logarithm of both sides and verifying the inequality for this simplified form?

Comment: You already know that $r_k \to C$. As a consequence, $\sum_{k = n}^\infty \log r_{k} - \log r_{k+1} = \log r_n - \log C.$ Now, $\log r_{k} - \log r_{k+1} $ has a neat form. Upper bound the logarithm in it up to the third order (note that the Taylor series of $\log(1+x)$ is alternating with diminishing terms), and bound the resulting sum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments above, consider $\log C/r_n$ and note that $C = \sum^\infty_{i=1} \log r_{i+1}/r_i$. So we have:
$$\log C/r_n = \sum^\infty_{i=n} \log r_{i+1}/r_i$$

Now we will bound this sum term-wise: [Use Jensen's inequality to show $\frac{2x}{2+x} < \log(1+x) < \frac{2x+x^2}{2+2x}$ for $x>0$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3703171/use-jensens-inequality-to-show-frac2x2x-log1x-frac2xx222x)

$$\frac{2x}{2+x} < \log(1+x) < \frac{2x+x^2}{2+2x}$$

And substituting $x = 1/n$ we get:
$$(n+1/2)\log(1+1/n) - 1 < \frac{1}{4n(n+1)}$$
We also have: $\log r_{n+1}/r_n=1-(n+1/2)\log(1+1/n)$
So now:
$$\log C/r_n = \sum^\infty_{i=n} \log r_{i+1}/r_i > -\sum^\infty_{i=n} \frac{1}{4i(i+1)}=-\frac{1}{4n}$$

Exponentiating each side and rearranging gives the desired result.

Comment: There are some sign errors - notice that rearranging gives you $r_n > C e^{-1/4n}.$ Also, $\log r_{i+1}/ r_i < 0,$ so that will give a better upper bound. On the other hand the method you've used does effectivly upper bound $\sum \log r_i/r_{i+1},$ and so it bounds $\log r_n/C$, which gives what you wanted.

Comment: Thanks for checking, fixed the sign error.